# Install catkin from source

Tags: ros, catkin, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the source files (https://github.com/ros/catkin branch: groovy-devel), a bug is fixed, that is not in the PPA repository for Ubuntu 12.04 (https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/5328).
I would like to install the new version from the source code like described here: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin .

When I do "make install", catkin is installed to /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/share.
But in ROS, still the catkin binaries from /opt/ros/groovy/bin seem to be used, the problem remains.
Manually copying the files to /opt/ros did not work either.
Could you explain step by step, how to install catkin from source?

Thanks and Regards,
Moritz

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191171/install-catkin-from-source/) by [baxter.irt](https://answers.ros.org/users/20077/baxter.irt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-08-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You want to use the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX
Documentation: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX

Related stack overflow posts:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003374/what-is-cmake-equivalent-of-configure-prefix-dir-make-all-install and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241922/how-to-use-cmake-install-prefix

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [baxter.irt](https://answers.ros.org/users/20077/baxter.irt/) on 2014-08-26**:
Thanks, it worked. Unfortunately it did not solve the targeted bug, but this is another topic.

```
mkdir ~/catkin-download
cd ~/catkin-download
git clone https://github.com/ros/catkin --branch groovy-devel
cd catkin
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/groovy ./
make
sudo make install
```